# Python pandas - get index of rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
df_raw.head()
    Ticker   FY Periodicity  Measure     Val                Date
0  BP9DL90  2009         ANN     CPX  1000.00 2008-03-31 00:00:00
1  BP9DL90  2010         ANN     CPX   600.00 2009-03-25 00:00:00
2  BPRTD89  2010         ANN     CPX   600.00 2009-09-16 00:00:00
3  BP9DL90  2011         ANN     CPX   570.00 2010-03-17 00:00:00
4  BPSRD74  2011         ANN     GRM    57.09 2010-09-06 00:00:00

[5 rows x 6 columns]
```

How do I filter out the table such that I get the rows with the max `Date` for each `Ticker` (irrespective of other column values)? The `Date` is in the Timestamp format.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html#pandas.Series.idxmax):

```
>>> df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) # in case `Date` column is string
>>> i = df.groupby('Ticker')['Date'].idxmax().values
>>> df.loc[i,:]
    Ticker    FY Periodicity Measure     Val       Date
3  BP9DL90  2011         ANN     CPX  570.00 2010-03-17
2  BPRTD89  2010         ANN     CPX  600.00 2009-09-16
4  BPSRD74  2011         ANN     GRM   57.09 2010-09-06
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to get the rows containing the max `Date` for a given combination of `Ticker` and `Measure`?

Comment: @user3294195 you can group by `['Ticker', 'Measure']`